# Controller and action names - compiler-verified

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In a constantly evolving MVC application, I would like to be able to get compiler checks on the correctness (or, at least, existence) of controller names and their action method names that are used to construct url's. So that

```
Url.Action("Index", "About")
```

becomes:

```
Url.Action("Index", Helper.GetControllerNameFromType(typeof(AboutController))
```

and it is guaranteed that `AboutController` type exists. I can deal with the controller name because from the type and its name the controller name can be obtained.

With the action method, however, I don't see a type-safe/compiler-checked way to get the method name. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 8):

[MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) has an [extension](https://code.google.com/p/mvccontrib/source/browse/trunk/src/MVCContrib/UrlHelperExtensions.cs?r=967) for `UrlHelper`. It should let you do this:

```
Url.Action<AboutController>(c => c.Index())
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the difference between MVC Futures project and MvcContrib?

Comment: As far as I know a difference is that you need to derive your controllers from FluentController. Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 1):

You could create an extension method that takes a generic or a type and get the name through convention. Something like

```
string ConventionBasedUrlAction(string action, Type controllerType)
{
    return Url.Action(action, typeof(controllerType).Name.Replace("Controller", string.empty));
}
```

If it is an extension you can keep the `Url.` syntax and customize the convention in the code, while keeping the original alternatives.

EDIT: and MvcContrib already has it, as Tim pointed out :)